# CodeNameOne: Custom dialog theme issue

Tags: codenameone

How can I create a theme for a dialog box?

I was trying to change the border style of the dialog box but the border style applies 2 times for an inner element and for an outer element. I was expected that the border style applies only to the inner element.

To be clearer, as I cannot add image to my post, it seems that the dialog does not consist only from the center box which is showed while dialog is active. The dialog UI consists from a “background form” which usually is transparent and from a container which overlay over the background form.  The last mentioned container contains de graphic representation of the “dialog box”.

My issue is that I can not apply my style only to the container which contains the dialog box but the style applies also to the background form.

How can I apply the border style only to the dialog box container element?

Any additional tips will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you applying the style? Are you using the theme to apply a style to the Dialog UIID as explained [here](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html).

Using `setStyle` or `getStyle` on a dialog component would be problematic and would not result in proper styling (you might get away with doing it on `getDialogComponent` but you should work with the theme).

Notice that to style a dialog you should use `Dialog`, `DialogTitle` & `DialogBody` UIID's and quite a few theme constants.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shai,
is clear now.

I’m doing a custom dialog starting from the  BlankDialog  element  provided in designer.
Because I started from BlankDialog I thought that overriding only UIID theme is enough.
I understood the BlankDialog structure wrongly thinking that is a simple empty form because is named "Blank…"

Is clear now that for every new UI object added, I should check if it has any other UI child to be customized together with the parent.

Thanks again.